# Is there a way to send a response to a Slack user via the Slack API Java SDK?

Tags: java, slack

I am writing a Slack Bot in Java and I want to send messages to the user in response to slash commands.

This can be done by sending HTTP requests to the `response_url` parameter coming with the slash command request using a http client library.

I was not able to send a message to the `response_url` using the Java SDK for Slack because none of the methods of the `methods` client Slack allow me to set the `response_url` (`chatPostEphemeral`, `chatPostMessage`, ...)

Is there a way to use the Java SDK for Slack to respond to slash commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried sending a request to the response_url by using the WebClient class to send a POST request with the desired payload?

something like:

```
public class RespondToSlashCommand {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String responseUrl = "https://hooks.slack.com/commands/YourResponseUrlHere";
    String message = "This is a response to a slash command.";

    // Initialize the Slack API client
    Slack slack = Slack.getInstance();
    SlackHttpClient slackHttpClient = slack.getHttpClient();

    // Prepare the JSON payload
    String jsonPayload = String.format("{\"text\": \"%s\"}", message);
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(jsonPayload, MediaType.parse("application/json"));

    try {
        // Send a POST request to the response_url
        Response response = slackHttpClient.postJsonBody(responseUrl, requestBody);

        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            System.out.println("Response sent successfully!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to send response: " + response.message());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: that works, at least I don't have to use restTemplate or some extra client. Though it would be nicer if I could use the `methods` API